# How to generate the Signature using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Here am trying to get the response for the below request but am getting the response as
{"message":"Signature expired: 20220813T114319Z is now earlier than 20220813T114400Z (20220813T114900Z - 5 min.)"}

Request Code:

```
import requests

url = "https://yyyyyyyyyy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/fulfillmentManagers/xxxxxxxxxx/fulfillments/zzzzzzzzzz"

payload = ""
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
  'X-UserId': 'bob',
  'X-Amz-Security-Token': 'Session Token',
  'X-Amz-Date': '20220813T114319Z',
  'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=Accesskey/20220813/us-east-1/sao-francisco/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-userid, Signature=ecfeeffa66c5cd0c6c27f481b7a46243dc258a401260d98320b577a7d9959035'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Tried to generate the signature key using [Signature Version 4 signing process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) as am still getting the signature error.

The AWS signature code:

```
import sys, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac, urllib, json, calendar, time
import requests

access_key = accesskey
secret_key = secretkey
method = 'GET'
service = 'sao-francisco'
host = 'yyyyyyyyyy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://yyyyyyyyyy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
spacename = f'prod/fulfillmentManagers/xxxxxxxxxx/fulfillments/zzzzzzzzzz'
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')
canonical_uri = endpoint + spacename
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'X-amz-Date:' + amz_date + '\n'
signed_headers = 'host;X-amz-Date'
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
canonical_querystring = ''
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
canonical_r = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' + amz_date + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + hashlib.sha256(
    canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, string_to_sign.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
Auth_value = f"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={access_key}/{datestamp}/us-east-1/sao-francisco/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-userid, Signature={signature}"
url = "https://yyyyyyyyyy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/fulfillmentManagers/xxxxxxxxxx/fulfillments/zzzzzzzzzz"
payload = ""
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
    'X-UserId': 'bob',
    'X-Amz-Security-Token': session_token,
    'X-Amz-Date': amz_date,
    'Authorization': f'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={access_key}/ {datestamp}/us-east-1/sao-francisco/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-userid, Signature= {signature}',
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Signature value is getting fail.

Comment: The signed URLs only work for about 5 minutes, you appear to be attempting to use the URL after that five minutes have elapsed, or the time on the machine creating the signature is off by some large amount.